# Front Page Displays in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, frontpage

I have two pages in wordpress ,one is home page and other one is blog page for the posts.

The thing though is that when I go to `Settings-> Reading` ,there I choose in the **frontpage display** option, the second option which is a **static page** .

In that setting, I have selected front page option for home page and for the posts page the blog page which is blank.

Besides that,while I have these options in the frontpage display, my posts do not **appear* in the home page that I have made. But when I leave it blank the front page option and I choose the posts page to be the home page then it works.

Please if anyone knows what to do i would really appreciate it.

Comment: What I have got is, you want to see post on Home Page.Is it so ?

Comment: yes that's the thing

Comment: But with the settings i described before,If possible